# NSInteger vs NSNumber and retrieving JSON data from itunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsnumber, nsinteger

Im trying to grab the artistId from this JSON

```
{
  "wrapperType": "track",
  "kind": "podcast",
  "artistId": 125443881,
  "collectionId": 523121474,
  "trackId": 523121474,
```

when creating my podcast object. but when i try to display this variable as a string, it returns null. how do i fix this?

This is where I am trying to access the artistID

```
  NSNumber *podcastID = episode.podcast.artistID;
NSString *episodeNumber = [episode.title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
NSString *deeplinkURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"podcast://%@/%@",podcastID, episodeNumber];
```

The string makes "podcastID" (null) in all instances.

And here is the iTunes response, where I assign the artist ID

```
     response.artistId = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"artistId"] integerValue];
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your mapping code to verify if the artistId is being correctly assigned.

Comment: You left out all of the important code. Show how and where you parse the JSON and assign the `artistId` property. And show how you try to display it as a string.

Comment: You share some JSON, but don't show us how you parsed it, nor how either `episode` or its `podcast` or its `artistID` is populated. Without that, no one can tell you why your `podcastID` variable is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSNumber instead:

```
self.artistId = [(NSNumber *)[response valueForKey:@"artistId"] integerValue];
```